# Change all table tags with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

i would like to change all  tag in a string into a set like [table1], [table2], etc.

For example,

```
Hello there <table class="table1"><tr><td></td></tr></table>

Some text here

<table class="table2"><tr><td></td></tr></table>

Some text here

<table class="table3"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

To:

```
Hello there [table1]

Some text here

[table2]

Some text here

[table3]
```

using

```
preg_match_all("@\<table (\s\S+)@s", $table_in_string, $match);
foreach ($match[1] as $key => $k) {
                                
}
```

My regular expression here does not seem to work.

Comment: Where did you get this regular expression from? Try `"@\<table(\s\S+)@s"`

Comment: Just remove the space after `<table ` http://regex101.com/r/iQ7oD1

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a single regular expression. Not, if a table-tag can also continue other html-tags. Using regular expressions to parse html is always a bad idea. You can't build a regex, which works under all possible circumstances. (Write your regex, and I can give you valid HTML which can't be handled by it)

Comment: I'm... not even going to bother linking. The pony. He comes. And he'll never stop coming until people learn to use the right tools for the right job.

Comment: Mm, you need something more like this: s/^(.*)<table class="\1"(.*)</table>(.*)$/\2/ this one won't work, it's just to get the idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 0):

[pregl_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) example:

```
$text = preg_replace( '/<table.*?class="(table\d+)".*?<\/table>/s', '[$1]', $text );
```

Comment: Nested tables might be problematic.